# how to get a desired order of this java script object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

lets see, i have a jquery parsed json object which is like this (but very bigger):

```
[
{answered: 0,
caller: 4,
callid: 4,
expired: 0,
groupid: 2,
location: "jubin",
name: "vahid",
personid: 3,
presense: 1367323732,
response: null,
text: null,
time: 1367336754,
type: 0},

{answered: 0,
caller: 6,
callid: 5,
expired: 0,
groupid: 2,
location: "jubin",
name: "vahid",
personid: 3,
presense: 1367323732,
response: null,
text: null,
time: 1367336766,
type: 0},

{answered: 0,
caller: 4,
callid: 4,
expired: 0,
groupid: 2,
location: "jubin",
name: "reza",
personid: 1,
presense: 1367392633,
response: null,
text: null,
time: 1367336754,
type: 0},

{answered: 0,
caller: 6,
callid: 5,
expired: 0,
groupid: 2,
location: "jubin",
name: null,
personid: 1,
presense: 1367392633,
response: null,
text: null,
time: 1367336766,
type: 0}
]
```

and i like to have something like this(short version):

```
[
{
callid: 4,
name: {"vahid", "reza"}
},

{
callid: 5,
name: {"vahid", null}
} 
]
```

can any one help,
i tried almost every things all for and ifs but certainly i'm doing it wrong in somewhere
thanks in forward

Comment: So it's an Array of Objects?

Comment: yes i want it to be simplified to use it elsewhere

Comment: You want to filter and reduce a long list of values. the library "underscore" offers good tools to do that, for example "groupBy" or "reduce".  See http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/hnReF/ for an implementation with "reduce".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `_`, http://jsfiddle.net/sWDsM/3/

This will convert `data` to an array like `arr[callid] = [name, ...]`

```
var arr = _.inject(data, function (memo, row) {
    memo[row.callid] || (memo[row.callid] = []);
    if (row.name != null && memo[row.callid].indexOf(row.name) == -1) {
        memo[row.callid].push(row.name);
    }
    return memo;
}, []);
```

And this will convert to what u expect

```
var result = [];
for (var key in arr) {
    result.push({callid: key, name: arr[key]});
}
```

Comment: thanx its more pro than my own found answer!

Answer (score 0):

hooray i did it!
its my result:

```
function calllog(log){//given log is my primary array
    var oLog = [];
    var tmpLog = [];
    var LL = log.length;
    for (var i=0; i<LL; i++){
        var thisID = log[i].callid;
        if(oLog.indexOf(thisID)<0){
            oLog.push(thisID);
        }
    };
    for (j in oLog){
        var tmpholder = [];
        for (k in log){
            if (oLog[j] == log[k].callid){
                tmpholder.push(log[k].name);
            }
        }
        tmpLog.push({
            'callid': oLog[j], 'name': tmpholder
        })
    };
    $(document.body).data('calllog', tmpLog);
};
```